# Eigen static lib memory align

Tags: c++, c++17, eigen

I am using C++17, GCC 7.4.0, Eigen 3.3.4

This is my minimal example. I have 2 classes: `B` and `C`. `C` is in a static library.
The program crashes with Segmentation Fault when trying to create an instance of `B`.

Static library is built with optimizations (Build Type: Release). If built without optimizations, the program does not crash.
The program only crashes when it's run in Debug. If I run it in Release, it does not crash.

main.cpp

```
#include "B.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    B b; // Program crashes here

    return 0;
}
```

B.h

```
#pragma once
#include "C.h"

using namespace std;

class B {
public:

    C c;

    B();
    ~B();


};
```

B.cpp

```
#include "B.h"
#include <iostream>

B::B() {
    cout << (uint64_t)this << endl; // This is never printed. Program crashes before this gets printed
}

B::~B() {
}
```

C.h

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Core>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Geometry>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

class C {
public:

    Quaterniond q;
    Vector3d v;

    C();
    ~C();

};
```

C.cpp -- this is packed into a static library

```
#include "C.h"

C::C() {
    v = Matrix<double, 3, 1>{0, 0, 0};
    Eigen::AngleAxisd y90(M_PI / 2, Eigen::Vector3d::UnitY());
    q = Quaterniond(y90);
}

C::~C() {

}
```

Also, if I remove `Quaterniond q` from the class `C`, re-build the static lib, and run the program, it does not crash.

EDIT:

This looks to me connected to [Eigen memory alignment issues](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStructHavingEigenMembers.html).
But, as it says in the link, I should not experience these issues since I am using C++17.

Anyways, according to @mmomtchev suggestion, I modified my code like this:

C.h -- modified

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Core>
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Geometry>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

class C {
public:

    Matrix<double, 3, 1, Eigen::DontAlign> v;
    Quaternion<double, Eigen::DontAlign> q;

    C();
    ~C();

};
```

And the program doesn't crash. So this supports my theory... It could be simply that one is not safe with C++17 if using static libs.

EDIT 2:

I posted a continuation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71647793/eigen-static-lib-aligned-free-double-free-or-corruption). I wasn't sure whether this is the same or a different problem.

Comment: This reeks of stale intermediate build artifacts. I would bet that a full clean rebuild would make this go away.

Comment: I know but, sadly, no... I believe it has something to do with this: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStructHavingEigenMembers.html 
but it clearly states there that these issues should not occur on c++17

Comment: Well, then if you disable alignment, your crash will go away? Does it?

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Run it in the debugger - you will see more info about the crash - which is probably an `abort()` call if it only crashes in `Debug`

Comment: Its Segmentation Fault, and it stops at creation of `B`, it doesn't show more than that since the static lib is built in Release.

Comment: I assume you are using linux? I failed to reproduce the issue (but I used gcc 7.5.0). The static library was compiled with the flags `-std=c++17 -DNDEBUG -O3` while the main program cpp files were compiled just with `-std=c++17`. Can you confirm that these are also the flags in your case? Any other flags that you use?

Comment: Otherwise, in my experience such crashes where mixed compilation modes are involved are often caused by ABI incompatibilities because something has a different size in debug than in release builds. I.e. that the library code sees different class sizes than the main program. Something like a `#ifdef NDEBUG` around member variables often causes this. As a cross-check, could you try to add a `static_assert(sizeof(C)==64)` to your `C.h` file (at least for me the size of C is 64)? If this is triggered in either the lib or the main program but not in both, then this is the issue.

Comment: Also, I noticed that the documentation of Eigen 3.3.4 does **not** yet contain the info "with C++17 everything is fine", while the current version 3.4.0 does. So maybe Eigen 3.3.4 still requires the `EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW` macro as described [in the manual](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStructHavingEigenMembers.html), despite C++17? I also noticed some source code changes related to the alignment stuff in 3.4.0 compared to 3.3.4. Could you try the most recent Eigen version?

Comment: @Sedenion this is the answer. Starting with version 3.4.0 Eigen uses the c++11 alignas keyword for static alignment. 3.3.x releases do not include this change. If you depend on 3.3.4 you will have to use `EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW`.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW does not help. As it says here https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStructHavingEigenMembers.html "In [c++17], this macro is empty" -> this seems to be true.
I added an EDIT to the continuation question.

Comment: @ancajic no, that macro is **not** empty in C++17 when you use Eigen 3.3.4. But it is empty starting with Eigen 3.4.0. Have you actually tried using it? Note that the documentation always points to the latest version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging from your comments at your [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71647793/3740047), you might be using different architecture options while compiling the library and the executable ([`-m...` flags for gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html))?

At least, I could reproduce the crash using Eigen 3.3.4 when I compiled the static library in gcc-7.5.0 with the flags `-O0 -DNDEBUG -g -std=c++17 -mavx`, while the executable is built with `-O0 -DNDEBUG -g -std=c++17`. This results in a segmentation fault in `_mm256_store_pd()`, which gets called when Eigen tries to assign a new value to `C::q` in the line `q = Quaterniond(y90);` in `C::C()`.
The crash is not completely deterministic.

The crash has the following reason: Object `B` and thus also its member `c` is created on the stack in the main executable. Its alignment is enforced by Eigen to a certain value. See the specialization of `plain_array` in Eigen. That value depends on the active architecture. Without any special flags it is 16 bytes, so  the address of the local variable `b` is e.g. `0x7fffffffe670`, and thus also of `B::c`, and thus also of `C::q` (all of them are the first members).
Then the code assign a new value to `C::q` from within the static library which was compiled with AVX in my example. Thus, it uses the AVX instruction `_mm256_store_pd()` for this, which requires 32 byte alignment. But the address `0x7fffffffe670` is only 16 byte aligned, not 32. Therefore, it causes a segmentation fault.

For me, sometimes the local variable happens to be 32 byte aligned, sometimes not. No idea what this depends on.

The macro `EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW` does not help here, because no dynamic memory allocation is involved. In fact, it wouldn't help anyway: In your [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71647793/3740047) the code involves dynamic memory allocations, but as explained there, you once again run into mismatching assumptions of alignment when the architectures are different.

The optimization level should have nothing to do with the problem, and AFAIK gcc does not automatically use different target architectures at different optimization levels. It also should have nothing to do with C++17 specifically as Eigen is using compiler specific attributes to align the data on the stack correctly.

The solution is to ensure that you compile the static library and the executable with the same architecture flags.