# Eigen static lib aligned_free "double free or corruption"

Tags: c++, eigen

This is a continuation of an [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70788173/eigen-static-lib-memory-align).

But this time with a hopefully better example. This simple test crashes when setting a vector.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04, gcc 9.3.0, c++17, eigen 3.3.7

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include "C.h"

using namespace std;

class B { 
public:
    C c;

    B() {
        cout << (uint64_t)this << endl;
    }
    ~B(){}

};

int main() {

    shared_ptr<B> b = make_shared<B>();

    b->c.v = VectorXd(5); // << crashes here
    // SIGABRT on `Eigen::internal::aligned_free` when trying to do `std::free()`

    return 0; 
}
```

Class C is linked as a static library. The static library is compiled in Release mode (`--std=c++17 -DNDEBUG -O3`), while the main program is run in Debug - without optimizations.
If both the static lib and the main program are run in Debug, then there is no crash.
Also, if they are both run in Release, there is no crash. The problem only occurs when the static lib is compiled in Release and the main program in Debug.

**C.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <Eigen/Core>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

class C {
public:

    VectorXd v;

    C();
    ~C();
};
```

**C.cpp**

```
#include "C.h"

C::C() {
    v = VectorXd(5);
}

C::~C() {

}
```

Comment: As in the other post, I failed to reproduce the issue (gcc 9.4.0, Eigen 3.3.7, Ubuntu 20.04). Could you post the full commandline that you used to compile the files? In case you are using cmake, enable [`CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE.html) to show the actual commandline used while calling the compiler.

Comment: I played around a bit, and got a crash when I compile the library with avx enabled (`-mavx`) and the main executable without avx (or rather, no specific option). I also get a crash, if it is vice versa. The crash also occurs in Eigen 3.4.0. It happens when the destructor `b->c.v.~VectorXd()` is called from the executable. The Eigen `free` functions are doing different things, depending on `EIGEN_DEFAULT_ALIGN_BYTES`, which has different values when AVX is enabled. Do you happen to compile one component with a specific and mismatching architecture or vectorization (`-march=...`, `-mavx`,...)?

Comment: Sedenion, thank you, can you make this an answer so I can confirm it?

Comment: Done. So you are also using different architecture flags?

Comment: Yes. I used march=native on the executable, but not on the library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case you compiled the library and the main executable with mismatching architecture flags ([`-m...` flags for gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html)), you can observe the crash. For example, when I compile the library with avx enabled (`-mavx`) and the main executable without avx, or vice versa, it crashes. The crash also occurs in Eigen 3.4.0. Moreover, it also occurs without optimization (`-O0`).

The Eigen `aligned_malloc()` and `aligned_free()` functions are doing different things depending on the value of the `EIGEN_DEFAULT_ALIGN_BYTES` macro, which has a different value when e.g. AVX (among others) is enabled or disabled. Eigen automatically selects the proper value depending on the used compiler flags. So, if you enable AVX only in the static library, the constructor of `C` uses `handmade_aligned_malloc()` internally, which is not returning the pointer received by `malloc()` directly but instead moves it a bit to ensure proper alignment. On the other hand, assigning a new value to `C::v` from the executable (which is compiled without AVX) will first try to free the memory by calling `b->c.v.~VectorXd()`, which then ends up calling just `free()` instead of `handmade_aligned_free()`. Thus, `free()` receives an address that does not point to the start of the allocated memory, which then causes the crash.
Of course, if you enable AVX in the executable and disable it in the library, you get mismatching calls to `malloc()` and `handmade_aligned_free()` instead, also resulting in a crash.

The solution is simple: Ensure that you compile the static library and the executable with the same architecture flags. If for whatever reason this is not possible, ensure that creation and destruction always happens in the same component. For example, you could make `C::v` private and allow modification of it only via functions that are implemented in the `C.cpp` file.

Note: Your [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70788173/3740047) is a bit different since it involves no dynamic memory management, while in the present post you use `VectorXd` which does use dynamic memory management.

Note 2: The described problem is unrelated to the use of `std::shared_ptr`. But for Eigen versions before 3.4.0 you might need to use `EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW` to ensure that the pointer `b` is properly aligned, regardless of the architecture and C++17; at least the original [Eigen issue](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/issues/1409) was implemented only for 3.4.0. But I might be wrong on this.